# How do I make a table view cell dynamic in size?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview

I am using the

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 100;
}
```

to make all the cells big enough for the biggest cell however I would like to make the cell big enough for its perspective contents.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you displaying in the cell. Do you need to make it big enough for a label of variable height? Or something else?

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the width of individual cells, that is part of the UITableView. You can return a different value for the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` for each row, that is how you make rows different heights. For example:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  MyThing *theThing = [arrayOfData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  return theThing.linesOfData * 17; //made up number for font height
}
```

Comment: This make sense and earned a +1